# What does "I don't want to die like X" mean when X is alive?

Tags: meaning

Some possible interpretations of "I don't want to die like X" seem to be:

1. Just like X, I, too, do not want to die.
2. Taking death non-literally: I do not want to die in the way that X has "died".
3. I do not want to die in the way X wants to (or will) die.

What is the standard interpretation here?

Answer (score 1):

With nothing more to go on, I'd take it to mean that X is closer to death (presumably by being considerably older) than the speaker and the speaker doesn't want to spend the last years of their life the way X does.

But that's filling in a lot of blanks that wouldn't be there if I knew who (or even what) X is? And I'd very likely change my answer if I had that information.

There isn't a "standard interpretation", and there can't be because whatever it is relates to the speaker's emotional response to "X" and we can't know that from just this.